# Problem with tablesorterPager when removing/updating table rows

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to use jquery table sorter with pagination.  I have problem when I do dynamic update of the table. After clicking  "#append" button(see the code) I'm changing the whole table body content. The paginator recognises this action, but when I click next it jumps two pages forward after first update,  three pages forward after second  update etc. Instead of one page...

I dont know what I'am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} , {headers: {1: {sorter: false}, 2: {sorter: false}, 3: {sorter: false}, 4: {sorter: false}, 5: {sorter: false}, 6: {sorter: false}, 7: {sorter: false}}})
      .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
      $("#append").click(function() {
        // add some html
        $.post("log_msg.asp", $("#msgForm").serialize(),
        function(data) {
          $('body').find("#myTable colgroup").remove();
          $("#msgs").html($("#msgs" , data).html());
          //$("#myTable").trigger("update")
          $('body').find("#myTable")
          .tablesorter( { widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']} )
          .tablesorterPager( { container: $("#pager") } );
      });
      // let the plugin know that we made a update
      return false;
    });

});
```

Any clue?

Thanks in advance
Cheers
Magda

Answer (score 1):

I think the event is getting attached multiple times. can you try this code which will basically unbind the click event and then bind it again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} , {headers: {1: {sorter: false}, 2: {sorter: false}, 3: {sorter: false}, 4: {sorter: false}, 5: {sorter: false}, 6: {sorter: false}, 7: {sorter: false}}})
      .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
      $("#append").unbind('click').click(function() {
        // add some html
        $.post("log_msg.asp", $("#msgForm").serialize(),
        function(data) {
          $('body').find("#myTable colgroup").remove();
          $("#msgs").html($("#msgs" , data).html());
          //$("#myTable").trigger("update")
          $('body').find("#myTable")
          .tablesorter( { widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']} )
          .tablesorterPager( { container: $("#pager") } );
      });
      // let the plugin know that we made a update
      return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: hi Shankar, thank you for a quick reply! Unfortunately it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this.. 
I opened the jquery.tablesorter.pager.js file and modified a little as follows.. 
Inside the construct function, add the following two lines

```
 $(config.cssNext,pager).unbind('click');
 $(config.cssPrev,pager).unbind('click');
```

just above

```
$(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
    moveToFirstPage(table);
    return false;
});
```

This worked for me.. hope it works for you as well. Good luck!
Vinod